# Rails 4 activerecord filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm re-writing a rails 1.x app I wrote many years ago and am running into problems filtering the activerecord with rails 4.

Models:

Glaze:

```
has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy

has_many :materials, through: :ingredients
```

Ingredient:

```
belongs_to :glaze

belongs_to :material
```

Material:

```
has_many :ingredients

has_many :glazes, through: :ingredients
```

There is a boolean checkbox for each material to indicate if it is a colorant or not. I want to filter the materials that are not colorant for each glaze record.

In my old rail 1.x app I used the code:

```
@batchingredients = @glaze.ingredients.find(:all, :order => 'amt DESC', :include => :material, :conditions => ['materials.colorant = ?', false])
```

I cannot get it to pass the non-colorant materials through. I am also unsure if this is a task I should make a scope for (I'm not a programmer and I don't think scopes were around the last time I worked with Rails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably best to create a scope on your ingredient model:

```
scope :without_colorant, -> { joins(:material).where(materials: { colorant: false }) }
```

then your controller would look like this:

```
@batchingredients = @glaze.ingredients.without_colorant.order(amt: :desc)
```

Comment: Presumably finding materials which aren't colorants might be useful elsewhere.  So maybe have a scope on `Material` `scope :not_colorant, { where(colorant: false) }` which can then be used on any material and you can use in your scope `scope :without_colorant, -> { joins(:material).merge(Material.not_colorant) }`